# Angular animation jumps to undesired value upon completion

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I've created an Angular animation (please see Stackblitz link below). I want an element to animate on entry, when the condition of the `ngIf` that wraps it becomes true.

The animation works at the beginning, expanding from `5px` to `50px` in `width`. 
But then, once it reaches the end, it just **jumps** to become full screen width!

Here is a reproduction of the issue:
**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flf7ha**

---

The code

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="addBars()">Toggle Bar</button>

<div *ngFor="let bar of bars">
  <div id="bar" @horizontalBarGrow [style.width.%]="bar.width"></div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
    trigger('horizontalBarGrow', [
        transition(':enter', [
            style({ width: '5px' }),
            animate('500ms ease-out', style({ width: '50px' })),
        ]),
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  bars = []

  addBars() {
    this.bars.push({ width: '10%'});
    this.bars.push({ width: '40%'});
  }
}
```

Comment: A quick-fix would be to add `width: 50px` on the `#bar` in css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR;** There is no states style only transitions style.

A `div` by default is full width :

```html
A div with the default width :
<div style="background-color: #3498db; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Once the transition ends, the div takes the defaults values again.

I suggest specifying states for your case :

```
trigger('horizontalBarGrow', [
  state('true', style({ width: '50px' })),
  state('false', style({ width: '0px' })),
  transition('false <=> true', animate(500))
])
```

[Here is an edit of your stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-53714352)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it is important that I use the `:enter` and `:leave` transitions because I want this code to work inside an `ngFor`. That is, I can't have  separate `showBar` variables for 20 "bars" in an array of bars

Comment: You want all the progressbars to show the exact same animation at the same time ?

Comment: Yes. The are actually not progress bars in this case, but part of a horizontal bar chart. See the update I've made in the StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flf7ha

Comment: You can define params in your animation and then pass them to the animation, here is a running example with this solution : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-53714352-3 . Another solution would be to encapsulate the div inside another div with the desired size, here is a running example with the second solultion : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-53714352-2